# Unable to add new dynamic fields in Solr 6.0

Tags: solr

I added a few new dynamic fields in solr-6.0.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf/managed-schema as follows:

```
   <dynamicField name="*_sst" type="string"  indexed="false"  stored="true" />
   <dynamicField name="*_sin" type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="false" />
```

Then I start solr and add a collection as:

```
bin/solr start -cloud
bin/solr create -c my_coll -shards 2 -replicationFactor 1
```

I see the dynamic-fields being picked up when I navigate to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/my_coll/files?file=managed-schema

```
<dynamicField name="*_sst" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_sin" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

However, when I send documents to this collection and query it, I am able to query by ***_sst** fields (which were meant to be stored-only) and I see ***_sin** fields in the result (which were meant to be indexed-only).

On seeing the http://localhost:8983/solr/#/my_coll/schema?field=FooPrefix.name2_sst, it does show that my **_sst** field is mapped correctly, but I am still able to search on it?
[image: screen-shot of Solr showing mapping of actual field to dynamic field]

Does anyone know what is not correct here?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of the file `managed-schema.xml` has lot many `dynamicFields` defined already.

And you field must be using one of it.

I think your field is using the

```
 <dynamicField name="*_t"   type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

or could be used

```
<dynamicField name="*_ss" type="strings"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

or there might be other dynamic field.

I would suggest you to either delete the rest all `dynamicField` which are not required and keep the ones which are added by you.

Once you are done with this, restart the server and re-index the data and check.

Comment: The original managed-schema has "*_ss" defined after "*_s". If what you said were true, then "*_ss" (or any other "*_is", "*_fs" etc. fields) would have never matched because prior to that matching, their smaller regular-expression counterparts would have matched (i.e. "*_i" would have matched before "*_is" and so on). But nevertheless, this could be some weird bug in Solr and I will try to see if your suggestion solves this problem. Will post my results of testing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your screenshot. It is all about **docValues**. Your attributes are accumulated between the field and type definition. And the definition for the type **string** now includes **docValues="true"**.

Which means the exact value search would still work against docValues even with **indexed=false**. And, as of schema version 1.6 (in Solr 5.5 and 6.0), [docValues can be returned](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/6.0.0/solr/CHANGES.txt#L497) even when **stored=false**.

If you don't like that, remove **docValues=true** from the **string** type or create another similar type without that flag. Or explicitly override it in your field definitions.